# Rechart : Tooltip disappear when mouse move over custom label (using a PieChart)

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, pie-chart, recharts

So I created a Pie Chart with a custom label component and a custom tooltip using ChakraUI.

The label only shows on some slices (where it's wide enough to accommodate the text)
The following problem is ONLY for slices with the label.

When moving the mouse over the slice, the tooltip show, unless you move your mouse over the label, which causes the tooltip to disappear.

Some Code:

```
const CustomChart = ({ data }: ChartProps) => {
  return (
    <PieChart width={400} height={240}>
      <Pie
        data={data}
        dataKey="value"
        innerRadius={50}
        outerRadius={100}
        cx="30%"
        cy="50%"
        labelLine={false}
        label={customLabel}
        style={{ outline: "none" }}
        isAnimationActive={false}
      />
      <Tooltip content={<ChartTooltip />} isAnimationActive={false} />
    </PieChart>
  );
};


const customDonutLabel: PieLabel<CustomDonutLabelRenderProps<ChartDataProps>> = (props) => {
  const slicePercentage = props.payload.value * 100;
  if (slicePercentage < 10) {
    return null;
  }

  const innerRadius = convertToNumber(props.innerRadius);
  const outerRadius = convertToNumber(props.outerRadius);
  const cx = convertToNumber(props.cx);
  const cy = convertToNumber(props.cy);
  const midAngle = convertToNumber(props.midAngle);

  const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
  const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;

  return (
    <text
      style={{ fontWeight: "semibold", fontSize: "md" }}
      x={cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN)}
      y={cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN)}
      fill={props.payload.color}
      textAnchor="middle"
      dominantBaseline="middle"
    >
      {Math.round(props.payload.value * 100)}
    </text>
  );
};

const ChartTooltip = (props: ChartTooltipProps) => {
  if (props.active && props.payload && props.payload.length) {
    const { value, name } = props.payload[0];
    const display = `${formatPercentage(value)}% - ${name}`;
    return (
      <ChakraTooltip label={display} openDelay={500}>
        <Text sx={tooltipStyleProps}>{display}</Text>
      </ChakraTooltip>
    );
  }
  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. A simple way to solve this is to use CSS to **set `pointer-events` to `"none"` on the custom label SVG elements** - doing this means the element will never be the target of a pointer event (in this case, mouseover) - you can [read more about pointer events on the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#none). You could do this one of two ways.

## Inline

In your `customDoughnutLabel` function, simply add the pointer-events property to the styles property on your text element:

```
<text
    style={{ fontWeight: "semibold", fontSize: "md", pointerEvents: "none" }}
    ...
    ...
```

## Site-Wide CSS

You could make this more generic by using CSS to target all Pie labels. Simply add the following rule wherever you define your global CSS:

```
.recharts-pie .recharts-pie-labels > .recharts-layer {
    pointer-events: none !important;
}
```